# Where did the term muslim come from and first used

Tags: arabic

I notice there seem to be a contary belifed that the word Muslim does not mean submitter to God.The word Muslim means peacemaker

Answer (score 1):

You should know that words in Arabic have a meaning لغوي and other meaning اصطلاحي the first the meaning in Arabic and the second the meaning in Islam. Usually the second اصطلاحي holds more meaning so if I say fiqh it means in Arabic comprehend but in Islam it means comprehend the sharia laws from it sources.

Muslim مسلم comes from اسلم surrender which we call in Arabic اسم فاعل . The one who surrender we call Muslim surrender his/her fate to someone (something like that)
Also there is root of the word Muslim from Salm سلم which means came without harm so it contains more than one meaning peace سلام surrender استسلم without any harm سالم